# How can detect which page I get from a same API url by JS or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am developing a software. Depending the state of customers' session, they will get different page back.

So all they visit is a url

http://xxx/order

when they visit this url, depends on their sessions' state, they will get two pages, one is index.html one is confirm.html

**How can I know which which page is return?
I cannot use jquery to find from URL since all url is http://xxx/order**

Comment: You're going to have to be way more specific and provide some code.

Comment: is this your page? guessing you can't change?

Comment: I was going to edit your question, but would have been too much dictation.. at the very least, you should do this `[http://xxx/order][1]` to your empty links, and add `[1]: #` at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

On each page you could have a div with css `display: none` and then have the file name inside that div.

You would then use jQuery `html()` to find the page:

On index.html

```
<div id="pageName" style="display: none">index</div>
```

And on confirm.html

```
<div id="pageName" style="display: none">confirm</div>
```

Then use jQuery to assign the page variable to `var page`

```
var page = $("#pageName").html();
```

Comment: this is a terrible solution.. if it's really a 'page', it will have a head tag that dictates the response header; which will include the title..